# HtmlUnit nothing happen when clicking on a Anchor

Tags: java, htmlunit

I use Htmlunit library to connect to this website http://www.tellmemorecampus.com/login.aspx
but when i use onlick method on the HtmlAnchor nothing happened...

this is my code :

````
        HtmlTextInput emailField = login.getHtmlElementById("userNameText");
        emailField.type(email); // works

        HtmlPasswordInput passwordField = login.getHtmlElementById("passwordText");
        passwordField.type(password); // works

        HtmlAnchor submit = login.getHtmlElementById("btnSignIn");
        HtmlPage result = submit.click(); // doesn't work

        System.out.println(result.asText()); ```

I have this 

``` Rosetta Stone
­


Choose an Interface Language


Rosetta Stone® Language Learning Suite
Rosetta Stone® Advantage


Welcome!
 test@mail.com
 sqsqs
Sign In
Forgot your user name or password?



Terms and Conditions
Privacy Policy
Agreements
Help

Copyright © 2014 Rosetta Stone Ltd. All rights reserved. ```

Thank you.
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try instead of

```
HtmlPage result = submit.click();
```

this code

```
HtmlPage result = submit.click();
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10_000);
result = ((HtmlPage) result.getEnclosingWindow().getEnclosedPage());
```

If this still does not work, please open an issue at https://github.com/HtmlUnit/htmlunit/issues and provide account data via my private mail.